# Xamarin XML intellisense not working

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin.forms, intellisense

I am trying to build a cross platform Xamarin.Forms application.

I have tested that the app works and it does indeed build successfully however, the IntelliSense isn't working and every content page (xml and cs) that I open floods the error log with multiple errors (but the app still builds fine? The errors are all saying that the XML stuff isn't recognised, such as the labels and Contents, even the includes at the top...)

I have read around and tried every fix I can find:

I have updated all nu get packages to their most recent build, I have cleared the Nuget cache, I have changed the "Open With" on XML files to Source Code (Text) with encoding, but still have multiple errors and no IntelliSense

Any help would be great, I am using VS 2017 on windows, using live player to run the app directly to iPhone

Edit: Providing a screenshot to show what the errors look like and where they occur...
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiaJj.png)

Comment: Are you passing a string xml or a filename?  When you use a string you usually use a PARSE(string) method and when you have the xml in a filename you use LOAD(filename).

Comment: just to clarify, I havent altered the application in any way. I have created a stock Xamarin.Forms (Cross Platform Shared) Application and as soon as i open the XAML file which comes with the project (The App.XAML file) It puts red squiggles under all of the XAML code and in the C# section it doesnt understand anything to do with XAML either, BUT it builds fine. Really strange!, i am adding an IMGUR to the main post to show what i mean.

Comment: I think you are missing following in c# : using Xamarin.Forms;  See following webpage for details : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/get-started-with-xaml?tabs=vswin

Comment: All of the includes are provided correctly by the stock app, my include of Xamarin.Forms is present, but when i hover over it, its says the namespace "Forms" doesn;t exist in the namespace Xamarin, but i must stress that this app works fine and even lets me add controls such as sliders / buttons etc...

Comment: I think the issue is with the namespaces you are using in the xaml.  Either the order of the namespace or the namespace (URL) are wrong or have been updated to a new version.

Comment: not sure why but my previous comment didnt commit when i posted it sorry, the namespace is included and i have narrowed it down to the android project causing all the issues. if i delete the project and only develop for IOS the intellisense works again, but i havent altered anything so its weird that it wont work.

Comment: May be it the project config settings.

Answer (score 0):

At first, be sure that the "open with" option for xaml file is set to "Source Code (text) Editor"

upgrading to XF 3.0.0.482510 seems to fix the intellisense problem
If you have resharper, set xaml intellisense to Visual Studio not to Resharper

Answer (score 0):

​In my case, the solution to the IntelliSense on Xamarin XAML files was tied to NuGet package references, I think especially the Xamarin.Forms package. If you have the yellow warning symbol on your packages, you have to get through the following steps on your specific project:

- Make sure it builds without errors
- Pass an `MSBuild /restore [path to the specific project]` in CL
- Pass a `.\nuget restore` at your solution in CL
- Close and reopen your solution
- Right-click on the concerned XAML file > Open With... > Make sure to have"XAML Designer" or "Xamarin.Forms Previewer" set to default for XAML files

You should now have IntelliSense.

​
​In my case, that made the yellow warnings disappear, then XAML IntelliSense worked again on Xamarin.Forms XAML files